# How do I extract data from XML columns into their own columns?

Tags: sql, xml

I have 280,000 rows that contain a column called `body`. This column has xml data.

A copy of one column value is shown below. I need to extract into new columns the data contained in the elements of the XML field `esn`, `timestamp_utc`, `Latitude`, `Longitude`, and `triggers`, with the column names being the same as the element names.

I have worked on this in the past, but gave up on it. I am not at a point I need to figure out how to do it. Please give me any suggestions you may have.

Thank you!!!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<telemetry>
   <esn>1127877</esn>
   <timestamp_utc>5/28/2011 9:18:30 PM</timestamp_utc>
   <latitude>59.023672</latitude>
   <longitude>-118.836408</longitude>
   <ignition>N</ignition>
   <geofence>0</geofence>
   <speed>0</speed>
   <heading>0</heading>
   <milestraveled>0.00</milestraveled>
   <triggers>Contact_State_Change, IO_1_Closed, No_Vibration_Detected, </triggers>
   <miscellaneous>Standard3</miscellaneous>
   <contact1counts>0</contact1counts>
   <contact2counts>0</contact2counts>
   <io1state>0</io1state>
   <io2state>0</io2state>
</telemetry>
```

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: Thank you!  I knew i was putting it in wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
SELECT  
   ID,
   body.value('(telemetry/esn)[1]', 'bigint') AS 'esn',
   body.value('(telemetry/timestamp_utc)[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS 'esn',
   body.value('(telemetry/longitude)[1]', 'float') AS 'longitude',
   body.value('(telemetry/latitude)[1]', 'float') AS 'latitude',             
   body.value('(telemetry/timestamp_utc)[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS 'triggers'
FROM
   dbo.YourTableNameHere
```

Does that work, and give you the right data??

Comment: I am getting an error when i run this code. It says: Cannot find either column "Body" or the user-defined function or aggregate "Body.value", or the name is ambiguous.

Comment: And yes, there is only one node in each XML.

Comment: Do you have any more suggestions?  This code seems like it would do the trick!

Comment: @John: I thought you said that your XML column is called `body` - if not, just replace it with your column name. Also: replace `YourTableNameHere` for your actual table name - obviously .... also: I included `ID` as another column from your table - not sure if you have that. You could put any column from your table there - or leave it out entirely...

Comment: It is called Body, and i did replace the table name. Sorry for being a pain. Here is a copy of a select statement, that pulls up the data.  "Select ID, Body from EmailStagingRecords"

Comment: @John - Is the data type for Body XML or something else? Do you use SQL Server?

Comment: Okay, the data type is text.  I think that is the problem.  I need to figure out how to change it and see if this code works.  I apppreciate all your help.  I am going to create a ssis package and see about changing the datatype, but not sure what to change it to.  Thank You!!

Comment: @John - Changing the data type to XML is a good thing but you can do the query using `cast(body as xml).value`.

Comment: @John: you should be able to change it to `XML` by using `ALTER TABLE dbo.EMailStagingRecords ALTER COLUMN Body XML` - try it on a **TEST** environment first, though !! You've been warned... and **NEVER** do this on a production box **without making a backup first**